# Datatables (Server-side processing) in Typo3 with FCE and Templavoila

Tags: php, datatables, typo3, templavoila

I'm trying to implement https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html into Typo3 (6.2LTS) with a flexible content element and templavoila. The result is a functioning but empty (No data available in table) table at the moment. I'm using the following php script:

```
<?php

class custom_datatable {  

var $datatable;    // reference to the calling object.  

function custom_table1($columns,$conf)    
{   

    global $TSFE;        
    $TSFE->set_no_cache();

    //do whatever you want here

    //db verbindung
    mysql_connect("my_host", "my_user", "my_password");
    mysql_select_db("my_database");

    /*
     * DataTables example server-side processing script.
     *
     * Please note that this script is intentionally extremely simply to  show how
     * server-side processing can be implemented, and probably shouldn't be used as
     * the basis for a large complex system. It is suitable for simple use cases as
     * for learning.
     *
     * See http://datatables.net/usage/server-side for full details on the server-
     * side processing requirements of DataTables.
     *
     * @license MIT - http://datatables.net/license_mit
     */

    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * Easy set variables
     */

    // DB table to use
    $table = 'my_table';

    // Table's primary key
    $primaryKey = 'id';

    // Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
    // The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
    // parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
    // indexes
    $columns = array(
        array( 'db' => 'Field1', 'dt' => 0 ),
        array( 'db' => 'Field2', 'dt' => 1 ),
        array( 'db' => 'Field3', 'dt' => 2 ),
        array( 'db' => 'Field4', 'dt' => 3 ),
        array( 'db' => 'Field5', 'dt' => 4 ),
        array( 'db' => 'Field6', 'dt' => 5 )

    );

    return $columns; 

}      
} 
?>
```

And get the following result in the source code:

```
 <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Field1</th>
            <th>Field2</th>
            <th>Field3</th>
            <th>Field4</th>
            <th>Field5</th>
            <th>Field6</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Field1</th>
            <th>Field2</th>
            <th>Field3</th>
            <th>Field4</th>
            <th>Field5</th>
            <th>Field6</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "Array"
        } );
    } );

    </script>
```

What am I doing wrong or is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order for the server side processing to work, you must pass the right data format into it,

```
{
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 57,
  "recordsFiltered": 57,
  "data": [
    [
      "Airi",
      "Satou",
      "Accountant",
      "Tokyo",
      "28th Nov 08",
      "$162,700"
    ],
    [
      "Angelica",
      "Ramos",
      "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)",
      "London",
      "9th Oct 09",
      "$1,200,000"
    ]
  ]
}
```

then you should also check the ssp class found on github for the server side-processing query
https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php

for additional information please visit
http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side

You should use it like this one:

in your datatables initialization

```
var your_datatable_variable_here = $('#your_datatable_id').dataTable({
responsive:true,
"bFilter": true,
"oLanguage": {
"sProcessing": "link_to_your_image_processing_gif/img/ajax-loader.gif'>"
},
"autoWidth" : true,
"bProcessing": true,
"bServerSide": true,
"sAjaxSource": "your_php_file_here.php"

})
```

PHP FIle:

```
function _dataTableServerSide($iQuery,$aColumns,$dReturnType){
    $iDisplayStart = $this->input->get_post('iDisplayStart', true);
    $iDisplayLength = $this->input->get_post('iDisplayLength', true);
    $iSortCol_0 = $this->input->get_post('iSortCol_0', true);
    $iSortingCols = $this->input->get_post('iSortingCols', true);
    $sSearch = $this->input->get_post('sSearch', true);
    $sEcho = $this->input->get_post('sEcho', true);
    $sLimit = "";

    if(isset($iDisplayStart) && $iDisplayLength != '-1'){
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".$iDisplayStart.", ".$iDisplayLength; //reverse execution of limit in sql
    }


    if(isset($iSortCol_0)) {
    $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for($i=0; $i<intval($iSortingCols); $i++) {
        $iSortCol = $this->input->get_post('iSortCol_'.$i, true);
        $bSortable = $this->input->get_post('bSortable_'.intval($iSortCol), true);
        $sSortDir = $this->input->get_post('sSortDir_'.$i, true);

            if($bSortable == "true") {
                $sOrder .= $aColumns[intval($iSortCol)]." ".$sSortDir;
            }
        }
    }

    $sWhere = "";
    if(isset($sSearch) && !empty($sSearch)) {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
            for($i=0; $i<count($aColumns); $i++) {
            $bSearchable = $this->input->get_post('bSearchable_'.$i, true);

                if(isset($bSearchable) && $bSearchable == 'true') {
                    $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".$sSearch."%' OR ";
                }
            }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ")";
    }


    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ ) {
        if ( $this->input->get_post('bSearchable_'.$i, true) == "true" && $this->input->get_post('sSearch_'.$i, true) != '' ) {
            if ( $sWhere == "" ) {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".$this->input->get_post('sSearch_'.$i, true)."%' ";
        }
    }

    switch($dReturnType) {
        case 1: {
            $sQuery = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns)).
            " FROM (".$iQuery.") ".$sWhere." ".$sOrder." ".$sLimit;
            $rResult = $this->db->query($sQuery);

            $sQuery = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() found_rows";
            $iFilteredTotal = $this->db->query($sQuery)->row()->found_rows;

            $sQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) counter FROM (".$iQuery.") ";
            $iTotal = $this->db->query($sQuery)->row()->counter;
        } break;
        case 2: {
            $sQuery = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns)).
            " FROM (".$iQuery.") AA ".$sWhere." "."ORDER BY gl_sub_id ASC LIMIT 1,10";//$sOrder." ".$sLimit;
            $rResult = $this->db->query($sQuery);

            $sQuery = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() found_rows";
            $iFilteredTotal = $this->db->query($sQuery)->row()->found_rows;

            $sQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) counter FROM (".$iQuery.") AA";
            $iTotal = $this->db->query($sQuery)->row()->counter;
        }
    }

    $output = array(
        'sEcho' => intval($sEcho),
        'iTotalRecords' => $iTotal,
        'iTotalDisplayRecords' => $iFilteredTotal,
        'aaData' => array()
    );



    foreach($rResult->result_array() as $aRow) {
    $row = array();

        foreach($aColumns as $col) {
            $row[] = $aRow[$col];
        }

    $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }

    return $output;
}
```

note: this is a working example, I am using code igniter as the base framwork,and MySQL as the database, if you want to convert it to PHP, just replace the code igniter functions with the standard php $GET methods

you will need to $GET the following from the client to make it work.

```
$iDisplayStart = $this->input->get_post('iDisplayStart', true);
$iDisplayLength = $this->input->get_post('iDisplayLength', true);
$iSortCol_0 = $this->input->get_post('iSortCol_0', true);
$iSortingCols = $this->input->get_post('iSortingCols', true);
$sSearch = $this->input->get_post('sSearch', true);
$sEcho = $this->input->get_post('sEcho', true);
$iSortCol = $this->input->get_post('iSortCol_'.$i, true);
$bSortable = $this->input->get_post('bSortable_'.intval($iSortCol), true);
$sSortDir = $this->input->get_post('sSortDir_'.$i, true);
$bSearchable = $this->input->get_post('bSearchable_'.$i, true);
```

and this is where the data is processed to be passed back to client page

```
$output = array(
    'sEcho' => intval($sEcho),
    'iTotalRecords' => $iTotal,
    'iTotalDisplayRecords' => $iFilteredTotal,
    'aaData' => array()
);



foreach($rResult->result_array() as $aRow) {
$row = array();

    foreach($aColumns as $col) {
        $row[] = $aRow[$col];
    }

$output['aaData'][] = $row;
}

return $output;
```

Comment: Thanks Arzgethalm. But how do I get the data in this format? ... and I'm not exactly sure what I should do with https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php?! Should I use it instead or add it?! Sorry I'm fairly new to datatables.

Comment: Thanks again Arzgethalm. But how do I replace the above CodeIgniter functions with the standard php $GET methods exactly?

Comment: get and post methods in php can be accessed like these, $_POST['iDisplayStart'],$_GET['iDisplayLength']

Comment: it also took me a while figuring it out. please check this, it is in php: https://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysql

Comment: I tried https://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysql as well and it seems to work. Yet ALL the data is rendered at the very top of the page outside of the html tags and not in the table. The problem I'm having is that Typo3 requires rendering the data via 'return' (http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/UserAndUserInt/Index.html). I opened another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242553/json-array-rendered-via-return-function-php-datatables-typo3